# Jetpack Compose custom textField text spacing issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I need to make a custom textfield but i can't get the right spacing above the text. I do not want padding in the textfield but i want spacing above the text so that when i scroll in the textfield the first and last line will not be stopped at the edge of the field.

I do want the text to scroll through the border as it does now.

How can i add spacing to the text?

I am using a custom BasicTextField:

```
BasicTextField(
    value = value,
    modifier = modifier
        .background(Color.Transparent, shape = shape)
        .indicatorLine(enabled, isError, interactionSource, colors),
    onValueChange = onValueChange,
    enabled = enabled,
    readOnly = readOnly,
    textStyle = mergedTextStyle,
    cursorBrush = SolidColor(colors.cursorColor(isError).value),
    visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
    keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
    keyboardActions = keyboardActions,
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
    singleLine = singleLine,
    maxLines = maxLines,
    minLines = minLines,
    decorationBox = @Composable { innerTextField ->
        // places leading icon, text field with label and placeholder, trailing icon

        TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
            value = value,
            visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
            innerTextField = innerTextField,
            placeholder = placeholder,
            label = label,
            leadingIcon = leadingIcon,
            trailingIcon = trailingIcon,
            singleLine = singleLine,
            enabled = enabled,
            isError = isError,
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            colors = colors,
            contentPadding = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldPadding(
                start = Spacing.spacing2,
                top = 0.dp,
                end = Spacing.spacing2,
                bottom = 0.dp
            )
        )
    }
```

This is how far i've come.
[image: Current situation]

Comment: means you don;t need `.padding(vertical = 10.dp)` on your basicTexField mod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if putting a scrollable column into the decoration box is the nicest solution but I was playing with it for a while now and this is what I came up with.

The content is scrolling through the border as you wished and it also does not end at the edge. Here is the simplified version:

```
val text = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

BasicTextField(
    value = text.value,
    onValueChange = { targetValue ->
        text.value = targetValue
    },
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(48.dp),
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
    decorationBox = @Composable { innerTextField ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .padding(all = 16.dp),
        ) {
            innerTextField()
        }
    }
)
```

The core of this solution is that I am not specifying max number of lines but I constraint the height to be `48.dp` (or any other) instead. This way, the `innerTextfield` composable is actually fully laid out and is overflowing the parent's size if that makes sense.

The problem with this solution though is that when you are typing, the text is not automatically scrolling. But I think it could work, if you put some scrolling logic whenever the value is changed.

Hope this helps at least a litte. :)

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot. Combined your code with mine and it solved the problem. I've set the height to `.heightIn(32.dp, 128.dp)` and added max lines. this added the scrolling functionality you were taking about.